# Is there any way to hide/remove android permissions dialog programmatically?

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have shown permission dialog using requestPermissions.

Is there any way to dismiss the permissions dialog programmatically ?

Comment: Please post some code and a bit of context to go along with your question. If we know why you want to dismiss the dialog we may be able to help you more.

Comment: Well it's a pretty specific usecase.Just want to know if it is possible . Couldn't find any complimentary API method to requestPermission which can dismiss the permission dialog without user intervention

Comment: There isn't a way to do that because it is a system dialog. If you absolutely need to clear it, restart the activity. Not recommended though.